# Implement sum_reverse() [Explode table result] in either hive/mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql, explode

We want to distribute quantity in equal distribution.
Table Sales is like below

```
product category qty
123     A        3
345     B        2
```

Output

```
product category qty
123     A        1
123     A        1
123     A        1
345     B        1
345     B        1
```

Comment: Why would you want this output

Comment: @Strawberry just curious how we can implement reverse of sum with equal distribution in each row

Comment: Generally, issues of data display are best handled in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hive

```
select  t.product
       ,t.category
       ,1           as qty

from    mytable t
        lateral view explode(split(space(t.qty - 1),' ')) e
;
```

---

```
+---------+----------+-----+
| product | category | qty |
+---------+----------+-----+
| 123     | A        | 1   |
+---------+----------+-----+
| 123     | A        | 1   |
+---------+----------+-----+
| 123     | A        | 1   |
+---------+----------+-----+
| 345     | B        | 1   |
+---------+----------+-----+
| 345     | B        | 1   |
+---------+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table of numbers, you can do:

```
select s.product, s.category, 1 as qty
from sales s join
     numbers n
     on n.n <= s.qty and n.n > 0;
```

In MySQL, you can generate such a table using variables.  For instance, if `sales` is big enough:

```
select s.product, s.category, 1 as qty
from sales s join
     (select (@rn := @rn + 1) as n
      from sales s cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) n
     on n.n <= s.qty and n.n > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out answer myself (this is in hive)

```
select category,main1.product,main2.qty from (select category,product,
split(substring(repeat(concat(1,','),int(qty)),0,int(qty*2)-1),",") as qty from 
(select collect_set(product) product,category,
sum(qty) qty
from sales) main
lateral view explode(product) main1 as product
lateral view explode(qty) main2 AS qty;
```